# Button in SharePoint Doesn't work in IE

Tags: css, sharepoint

Button/link in SharePoint doesn't execute in IE. I believe it is because using the button tag inside an anchor tag isn't supported. **Could I use inline CSS to display the link as a button?**

Here is my current code (modified):

```
    <a href="/sites/AAAAA/Lists/MDCR/NewForm.aspx?SOURCE=https%3a//sp.com/sites/AAAAA/SitePages/Master%20Data%20Change%20Requests.aspx"><button type="button">​Ad​d NEW Request</button>​</a> ​
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<button>` tag supports putting HTML inside it; one option would be to simply invert the nesting of your `<a>` and `<button>` tags.

A second option would be to add an onclick event handler to your button so that it navigates to the specified URL. You could do this declaratively by adding `onclick='window.location.href="your.url.here";'` or programmatically via JavaScript by grabbing the button (such as by using `document.getElementById()` or `document.querySelector()`) and then calling `.addEventListener("click",function(){window.location.href="your.url.here"});` on it.

A third option would be to use CSS to decorate your `<a>` tag to look like a button. This is my favorite option, since it gives you more control over the appearance and behavior of the "button."

Here are examples of all three approaches:

```css
button a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button {
  padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
  background-color: lightgray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  font-family: Segoe UI;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: rgb(250, 250, 250);
}
```

```html
<p>

  <button><a href="www.bing.com">Link inside a Button</a>
  </button>

</p>

<p>

  <button onclick='window.location.href="www.bing.com";'>Normal Button</button>or
  <input type="button" onclick='window.location.href="www.bing.com";' value="Alternative Button">

</p>

<p>

  <a href="www.bing.com" class="button">Fake Button Using CSS</a>

</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the great examples. I tried all three methods, but SP either strips out the code when I go to save the page, or doesn't interpret the CSS...meaning it shows up as plain text. I'm not sure why the Edit Source feature doesn't allow all html. It's as if the code is compiled and adapted when you close out of the "Edit Source" and return to the rich text editor. I get a message that says "Warning: Some of your markup was stripped out. Try using the Embed command"

Comment: You can get around that by putting your markup in a text file, uploading it to a document library, then adding a content editor web part to a page. Use the content editor web part's "content link" property to link to the text file. SharePoint then won't strip out JavaScript. Also, make sure your CSS is nested within `<style></style>` tags.

Comment: Thanks Thriggle. I ended up using the Script Editor web part to place my CSS snippet there...then reference it in the <a> tag within "Edit Source". Works great.